# Is there a better way to refresh WebView?

Tags: android, refresh, webview, reload

Ok.  I have looked EVERYWHERE and my little brain just can't understand a better way to refresh an activity.  Any suggestions that I can understand would be great.  :)

Here is the java code:

```
package com.dge.dges;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class dgeActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings();
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.websitehere.php");
        
        Button newButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(dgeActivity.this, dgeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the `main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/new_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Refresh"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't like the idea of just re-stacking activity after activity.  There has to be an easier way to refresh the webview.  Please help.  :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

1) In case you want to reload the same URL:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.websitehere.php");
```

so the full code would be

```
newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    dgeActivity.this.mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.websitehere.php");
   }});
```

2) You can also call `mWebView.reload()` but be aware this reposts a page if the request was POST, so only works correctly with GET.

Comment: Josh answer is the correct one. Your will keep reloading the same url.

Comment: Once after you load a page , you have set the visibility of that button to INVISIBLE like this "newButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)"

Comment: `webView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" ); ` this has helped me, webview.reload was not working me, But this needs,   `yourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` enabled in webview Settings

Answer (score 95):

You could call an `mWebView.reload();` That's what it does

Comment: reload() doesn't seem to work if the original query was a WebView.postUrl()

Answer (score 56):

The best solution is to just do `webView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );`. This should work on all versions and doesn't introduce new history entries.

Comment: Nice solution! However, this will require that you enable JavaScript in your WebView widget with 
`yourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: I think this should be the best answer. As you wont really need to specify url based on the correct best answer here.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me.

just put under onCreate metode

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reload_btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            web.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );             
        }
    });
```

This is the code  that can reload a website in a webView

```
web.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );
```

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
mWebView.loadUrl(mWebView.getUrl().toString());
```

Comment: or `mWebView.reload()`.

Answer (score 3):

Refreshing current webview's URL is not a common usage.
I used this in such a scenario: When user goes to another activity and user come back to webview's activity I reload current URL like this:

```
public class MyWebviewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    ....
    ....
    ....
    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
            String url = mWebView.getUrl();
            String postData = MyUtility.getOptionsDataForPOSTURL(mContext);
            mWebView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
    }
}
```

You can also use WebView's `reload()` function. But note that if you loaded the webview with `postUrl()`, then `mWebView.reload();` doesn't work. This also works

```
String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
mWebView.loadUrl(webUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `onFormResubmission` in `WebViewClient`

```java
@Override
public void onFormResubmission(WebView view, Message dontResend, Message resend){
   resend.sendToTarget();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me for correctly refreshing a POST request. The other suggested solution of a JS reload adds a history record. Namely each refresh will result in another entry in the back stack.

Answer (score 0):

> **The best and fastest way and should enable JavaScript**

```
WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             webView = findViewById(R.id.webview_sample);
             WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
             webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
         //for Speed up downloading and rendering   
         webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
            webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
            webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);

//refresh btn
          Button btn=findViewById(R.id.close_ad_ref);
          btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 //you can placed in any palce as your need
                 webView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );
            }
        });


}
```

Answer (score -4):

Yes for some reason WebView.reload() causes a crash if it failed to load before (something to do with the way it handles history). This is the code I use to refresh my webview. I store the current url in `self.url`

```
# 1: Pause timeout and page loading

self.timeout.pause()
sleep(1)

# 2: Check for internet connection (Really lazy way)

while self.page().networkAccessManager().networkAccessible() == QNetworkAccessManager.NotAccessible: sleep(2)

# 3:Try again

if self.url == self.page().mainFrame().url():
    self.page().action(QWebPage.Reload)
    self.timeout.resume(60)

else:
    self.page().action(QWebPage.Stop)
    self.page().mainFrame().load(self.url)
    self.timeout.resume(30)

return False
```

Answer (score -7):

Why not to try this?

Swift code to call inside class:

```
self.mainFrame.reload()
```

or external call

```
myWebV.mainFrame.reload()
```

Comment: The question is related to Android not Swift/iOS development, so your solution doesn't work because Android does not provide that reload() function.