# Refresh WEBVIEW when switching TABS

Tags: android, android-webview, android-tabhost

I have 3 different WebViews embedded in TabViews. How can I refresh the WebView I am leaving when I switch to a different tab? Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563325/is-there-a-better-way-to-refresh-webview ? First hit on Google.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to refresh selected WebViews if certain tabs are selected. Like if tab1 is selected I want to refresh webviews 2 and 3, but not webview 1 because thats the tab I am going to and I do not want to wait for loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [OnTabChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html) and then reload your webview on the hook.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload activity when you switch to the webView tab. It will reload the webview and the issue would be solved. just add this flag to the tabspec activity declaration:  .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I figured it out by using
 if("TAB_1".equals(tabId)) {
 // code here
}