# Android WebView not refreshed after webview content has been modified by JavaScript

Tags: android, android-widget, android-webview

My application uses a `WebView` with transparent background in which some styling properties of the elements are modified by JavaScript.

The problem: `WebView` is not refreshed according to the modified properties. When `WebView` is redrawn (e.g., due to user orientation change) the `WebView` is updated correctly.
I reproduced the problem on Android 3.2 (on Samsung GT) but on Android 2.1 and 4.3 all works fine.

A sample code that reproduces the problem:
Obviously when the first image is tapped it should disappear, and tap on the second one should move it. If the background color of the `WebView` is changed to be opaque, or if I remove the image displayed below the `WebView` all works fine...

HTML loaded by the web view. :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body >     
        <img style="position:absolute;left:0px" onclick="this.style.display='none';" 
            src="http://flv.justad.tv/gallery/assets/trickplay/justad/tp-pause.png" />  

        <img style="position:absolute;left:200px" onclick="this.style.top='200px';" 
            src="http://flv.justad.tv/gallery/assets/trickplay/justad/tp-ff.png" />

    </body>
</html>
```

Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

     <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/display_background" />

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/WebviewContainer">

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Application `Activity`:

```
    public class TestImageMoveActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        RelativeLayout webviewContainer =        
                  (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.WebviewContainer);
        WebView web = new WebView(this);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        web.setLayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        web.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        webviewContainer.addView(web);

        web.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.12/myWeb/localTmp/testImageMove.html");
    }
}
```

Screen shot before tap:

[Screen shot before tap](http://flv.justad.tv/gallery/resources/android_before_tap.jpg)
[Screen shot after tap on both images](http://flv.justad.tv/gallery/resources/android_after_tap.jpg)

Comment: Your screenshot links are broken (permission denied).

Comment: Sorry for that... Links should work now

Comment: No need to apologize, just saying so you notice it. :)

Comment: just check out this link it will give some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563325/is-there-a-better-way-to-refresh-webview

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. The problem arises because you must save the state of your `WebView` during an orientation change.  Without doing so, the webpage is treated as if loading for the very first time.  That means any changes that were applied dynamically with JavaScript are completely lost.

**The preferred/correct way:**
Depending on the complexity of your web, this may take a little work since there's no built in way to do so. You must manually handle what dynamic changes need to be saved within JavaScript itself.  A high level view of the steps to take:

1. Activity's `onSaveInstanceState()` invokes a JavaScript function, e.g. saveState()
2. saveState() records necessary information to DOM storage, e.g. `localStorage`.
3. Activity's `onRestoreInstanceState()` invokes a JavaScript function, IE restoreState()
4. restoreState() loads information from DOM storage and updates webpage to original state.

**The ill advised but easy way:**
Override your activities `configChanges` within the manifest. That'll prevent the activity from being recreated and hence the webpage should not reload.

**Further Reading:**
[Information about recreating an Activity from saved state](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)
[Pros/Cons to overriding configChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7990543/1243753)

Answer (score 1):

> Make a method to refresh webview
>   ex 
>   
>   `void refreshWebview(WebView webView)
>      {
>      webView.reload();
>      }`
>
> call refreshWebview() from your javaScript or anywhere from your code using interface.

Answer (score 0):

try manually reload webview:-
`web.reload()`