# Refresh webview when pressing button?

Tags: android, xml

So what I'm trying to do is to refresh my webView using a button in the actionbar, the problem? Well, it is easier to explain with some code.

This is at the bottom of my MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final String url=getArguments().getString("url");

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,container, false);
WebView wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl("http://feedit.themeister.se/app/"+url+".php");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
return rootView;
}
```

And in order to refresh the webView I need the "url" string but the string is created inside the onCreateView, above that I have this one to actually make the refresh-button work

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_refresh:
        // Here should some code be placed but I don't know what to place
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I can't use the url string or the "wv" for webView. Anyone know how I should make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to call again `wv.loadUrl("http://feedit.themeister.se/app/"+url+".php");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to refresh WebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563325/is-there-a-better-way-to-refresh-webview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use the url string or the "wv" for webView. Anyone know how I should make this work?

This is because your two variables, the url and `wv` are locals, meaning that they only exists under your `onCreateView` method.

To use your variables in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method, put their declaration outside of their method, like in top of the class.

So, in steps :

- put `WebView wv;` on top of the class,
- Change `WebView wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);` in `wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);`
- Modify your `onOptionsItemSelected` to refresh the webview like this :

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_refresh:
          wv.loadUrl(wv.getUrl());
          return true;
      default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  ```

I also suggest you to reed the basics of Java about variable scopes, (like this one : http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) and look for other tutorials about java basics before going on Android code.

Comment: There are two problems. One new problem and one existing. 1. When putting the `wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);` inside onOptionsItemSelected I get an error saying "rootView cannot be resolved" and just adding the line I have below in onCreateView doesn't work because I don't have the inflater and such. 2. Still cannot use "url".

Comment: 1. No no, you misunderstood, you don't have to change the position of `wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);`, just to remove the `WebView` at start of the line.

2. You don't have to use the variable `url` in the `onOptionsItemSelected`, just use `wv.loadUrl(wv.getUrl());`.