# Android WebView not loading

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, null, "utf-8", null)`; method to refresh my `WebView`, but it is not refreshing the `UI` the second time. It works well the first time.

Comment: Please post the code that you have implemented for doing this, so that we can properly point out your mistakes and help you fix them.

Comment: `webView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );` and make sure you have this line of code `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: I am trying to post the code but the site is warning me with the message "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking"

Comment: Hi Salman and in the comment section i could not post the answer as it is too long

Comment: I have the line of code webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); but still no use

Comment: @SriramTej don't answer to your question just click on the edit option between the share and flag options below the two Tags of android and android-webview and there post your code.

Answer (score 0):

How would you like to refresh your `Webview`? Depends on your project requirements. [Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563325/is-there-a-better-way-to-refresh-webview) it if you want it at `OnCLickListener`. If you want your data from assets or any directory to a `Webview` you can use `loadDataWithBaseURL()` with appropriate parameters.

You can load image via `Webview` using the following code

```
String html;
html = html.concat("<html><head><title>TITLE!!!</title></head>");
html = html.concat("<body><h1>Image?</h1><img src="icon.png" /></body></html>");
webview . loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

for more details [try](http://myexperiencewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-loaddatawithbaseurl.html) it

Comment: Actually i am trying to post some post data to server  everytime user clicks a button with new values and will load the webpage with the response data i have received from the server and in this context it is a image source.

Comment: it would be clear for me if i can see your code. check my updated answer

Comment: I tried your above solution but no use  user3384985 and i am trying to post the code here

Comment: This is my Asynctask which i have been calling in onCreate() method

Comment: private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  if (result != null) {
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, result, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
   }}

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          // some http post request data here which finally throws some response
return stringBuilder.toString();
   return null;}}

Comment: have you formatted your code(result) to html before webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, result, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);  execution in onPostExecute(String result)?

Comment: it is already formatted . I mean the result itself is coming in HTML format

Comment: The above problem has been solved with the below piece of code
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  if (webview != null) {
   webview.destroy();
   webview = null;
  }
  super.onDestroy();
 }

I don't know the exact reason behind this but above code played as a trick.