# ( Android ) Webview refresh button

Tags: java, android, webview, reload

I'm trying to create a button to reload a Webview but ( sorry I'm new in android developement ) I didn't find a way to do it ( even in stackoverflow )

Here is the Mainactivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.d4rkunicorn.partyhard.R.id.webView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("url");
    }

}
```

The webview.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/webview.xml">

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="REFRESH"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: use button onclick and call webview

Comment: See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563325/is-there-a-better-way-to-refresh-webview

Comment: Already tried it, didn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Activity class :

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.d4rkunicorn.partyhard.R.id.webView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("url");

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                webview.reload();
                
            }
        });
    }

}
```

In Layout XML  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/webview.xml">

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="REFRESH"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Android studio show "Error:(29, 39) error: cannot find symbol class OnClickListener" on build

Comment: import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  in activity

Comment: My pleasure :).  Please up vote to answer so it's help to other

Answer (score 1):

There many possible way to reload your webview:

1. you can use  `webview.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );` inside any method/action event
2. `webview.loadUrl(webview.toString); //getting the webview URL and use to reload ur web page`
3. `webview.loadUrl(url); // you can use your desire URL to reload your web page`
4. `webview.loadUrl( "onclick=\"window.history.back()"\");`

Answer (score 0):

You can reload your web view or you can use below code :

```
yourActivity.this.webView.loadUrl(url);
```

on your button click.