# How to refresh my page and it's content in an android webview?

Tags: android, web-applications, webview

I tried refreshing my page in an android webapp using the html refresh meta tag, the page refreshes but my page content updates didn't .

How can I refresh both the page and it's content in android webview?

Answer (score 0):

Just reload the url will do what you want.

either `mWebView.reload()` or `mWebView.loadUrl(URL)` is fine.

similar answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563482/1573348